# can't read hive table after data load

Tags: hive, beeline

I created a table in Hive (beeline), the command below:

```
create table testemp(id int, name string, role string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

I've a small custom file as well with sample records as:

```
12345,John,Doe
67890,Mary,Poppins
2234,Poppy,Mariann
```

Trying to load the data from this file to the table create above:

```
load data inpath '/tmp/dataFiles/data.csv' overwrite into table testemp;
INFO  : Loading data to table testemp from hdfs://HAN/tmp/dataFiles/data.csv
INFO  : Table testemp stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=169, rawDataSize=0]
No rows affected (0.132 seconds)
```

As you see the data didn't load even.
And now when I try to do a select on the table, I just can't.

```
select * from testemp;
Error: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server (state=,code=0)
```

I've no idea why this error even popped up. Can someone reproduce the problem on their kerberized cluster via beeline?

Any ideas?

Comment: I checked the input & output formats as well, doesn't work with those either.

Comment: Just checked it is working as expected.  What version are you using?

Comment: @Bala Hive is 0.14

Answer (score 0):

just to be sure please confirm your file name as data or data.csv and mention accordingly. And where the file is stored either local file or HDFS, if local file system then (load data local inpath.....) will be used.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean that I'm running incorrect statements but if it is, then it's all evident in my description above. I'm using the file present in HDFS location, if it weren't then the file load would've failed.
Once the load is done, I cross check the file is copied to the HDFS location of the table as well. It's just the reading of the data that's not happening.